# "The remote name could not be resolved" : While deploying on Azure portal

Tags: .net, azure, web-config, azure-caching, azure-deployment

The solution runs fine locally but after deploying on azure portal it's throwing error[image]

What the changes in web-Config should I make while deploying?
I have tried this (with removing the  element)
`<autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="[[newCacheNamespace].cache.windows.net" />`

But after deploying it's not recognizing the autodiscover.
(I am deploying the two file generating after clicking on package- FYI)

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-managed-cache-and-in-role-cache-services-to-be-retired-on-11-30-2016/), Azure Managed Cache and In-Role Cache services have been retired on 11/30/2016. After this date, **the Managed Cache Service will be shut down**, and the In-Role Cache service will no longer be supported.

We suggest you migrate exist cache to Azure Redis Cache. Azure Redis Cache provides more features and a better value overall. For more information on migrating, please visit the [Migrate from Managed Cache Service to Azure Redis Cache documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-migrate-to-redis) webpage.

Comment: @Amon:Thanks for answering. I think you forgot to put the hyperlink on Document as document is not opening. please provide that so that I can go through it.

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-managed-cache-and-in-role-cache-services-to-be-retired-on-11-30-2016/